# How to generate documentation from Cucumber / Gherkin?

Tags: documentation, cucumber, python-sphinx, gherkin

I like the idea of [relishapp.com](http://relishapp.com), i.e. that you have Cucumber / Gherkin features and you generate "living docs" from them. However, the Relish SaaS [is awful](https://github.com/apiaryio/gavel-spec/issues/21).

I'm looking for an alternative. Ideally self-hosted Open Source like [Sphinx](http://sphinx-doc.org/), but I'm not completely opposed to SaaS solutions. Especially Sphinx would be great as I could combine it with other docs and use [readthedocs.org](http://readthedocs.org/) for deployment.

So the question is: **What would be the easiest way to generate HTML docs from Gherkin features?**

Comment: I wrote a Sphinx extension, feel free to try it and give feedbacks :)
https://cblegare.gitlab.io/sphinx-gherkin/

Answer (score 4):

There is one more option **Cukedoctor** https://github.com/rmpestano/cukedoctor

You can host within company network using **SimpleHTTPServer** ( http://2ality.com/2014/06/simple-http-server.html )

Answer (score 3):

I've used [yard-cucumber](https://github.com/burtlo/yard-cucumber) to do that before. It worked out pretty well.